# In HTML, 5 inline images with "width:20%" each don't add up to 100% device width on IPad

Tags: html, css, ipad, browser, width

when I create 5 or more inline placed images and set the width for each one so the total would amount to 100%, the total width is a little less than 100%.

The strange thing is that if I place 1, 2, 3 or 4 images in the exact same manner, the total width is 100%.

Also, this problem only happens on Ipad (both default Safari and Chrome browsers), it doesn't happen on Android mobile (Chrome or default) and desktop (Chrome) as far as I tested.

Here is a link to a screenshot of what I'm talking about. Note that the five upper images are set to width 20% each, and the bottom 4 images are set to width 25% each.

http://s11.postimg.org/5fnut3agi/image.jpg

Here is my complete HTML file. I know it's not what a proper HTML should look like, but I'm a beginner, so don't judge :)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <script src="jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
 <script type='application/javascript' src='fastclick.js'></script>

 <script>

  $(function() {
   FastClick.attach(document.body);
  });

  $(function() {
   $('.tabs .tab-links a').on('click', function(e)  {
    var currentAttrValue = jQuery(this).attr('href');

          // Show/Hide Tabs
          $('.tabs ' + currentAttrValue).show().siblings().hide();

          // Change/remove current tab to active
          $(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

          e.preventDefault();
      });
  });

 </script>

 <style type="text/css">

  * {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   width:100%;
   overflow-x:hidden;
  }

  .tab {
   display:none;
  }

  .tab.active {
   display:block;
  }


  ul {
   list-style-type: none;
   line-height: 0px;
   font-size: 0px;
  }


  .tab-links li {
   display: inline;
   list-style:none;
  }

 </style>
</head> 

<body>

 <div class="tabs">
  <ul class="tab-links">
   <li class="active"><a href="#tab1"><img src="http://s7.postimg.org/i0qokrbh7/Placeholder.png" style="width:20%"></a></li><li><a href="#tab2"><img src="http://s7.postimg.org/i0qokrbh7/Placeholder.png" style="width:20%;"></a></li><li><a href="#tab3"><img src="http://s7.postimg.org/i0qokrbh7/Placeholder.png" style="width:20%;"></a></li><li><a href="#tab4"><img src="http://s7.postimg.org/i0qokrbh7/Placeholder.png" style="width:20%;"></a></li><li><a href="#tab5"><img src="http://s7.postimg.org/i0qokrbh7/Placeholder.png" style="width:20%;"></a></li>

   <li class="active"><a href="#tab1"><img src="http://s7.postimg.org/i0qokrbh7/Placeholder.png" style="width:25%"></a></li><li><a href="#tab2"><img src="http://s7.postimg.org/i0qokrbh7/Placeholder.png" style="width:25%;"></a></li><li><a href="#tab3"><img src="http://s7.postimg.org/i0qokrbh7/Placeholder.png" style="width:25%;"></a></li><li><a href="#tab4"><img src="http://s7.postimg.org/i0qokrbh7/Placeholder.png" style="width:25%;"></a></li>

  </ul>

  <br><br>

  <div class="tab-content">
   <div id="tab1" class="tab active">
    <p>Veikiaz</p>
    <p>Donec pulvinar neque sed semper lacinia. Curabitur lacinia ullamcorper nibh; quis imperdiet velit eleifend ac. Donec blandit mauris eget aliquet lacinia! Donec pulvinar massa interdum risus ornare mollis.</p>
   </div>

   <div id="tab2" class="tab">
    <p>Tab #2 content goes here!</p>
    <p>Donec</p>
   </div>

   <div id="tab3" class="tab">
    <p>Tab #3 content goes here!</p>
    <p>Donec pulvinar neque sed semper lacinia. Curabitur lacinia ullamcorper nibh; quis imperdiet velit eleifend ac. Donec blandit mauris eget aliquet lacinia! Donec pulvinar massa interdum ri.</p>
   </div>

   <div id="tab4" class="tab">
    <p>Tab #4 content goes here!</p>
    <p>Donec pulvinar neque sed semper lacinia. Curabitur lacinia ullamcorper nibh; quis imperdiet velit eleifend ac. Donec blandit mauris eget aliquet lacinia! Donec pulvinar massa interdum risus ornare mollis. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Ut euismod tempus hendrerit. Morbi ut adipiscing nisi. Etiam rutrum sodales gravida! Aliquam tellus orci, iaculis vel.</p>
   </div>
   <div id="tab5" class="tab">
    <p>Tab #5 content goes here!</p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is the part where the images are included. As you can see from the full HTML code, they are both in the same divs and same ul. Note that I replaced the image source with a link in the full HTML, so that snippet could display the images.

```
<li class="active"><a href="#tab1"><img src="placeholder.svg" style="width:20%"></a></li><li><a href="#tab2"><img src="placeholder.svg" style="width:20%;"></a></li><li><a href="#tab3"><img src="placeholder.svg" style="width:20%;"></a></li><li><a href="#tab4"><img src="placeholder.svg" style="width:20%;"></a></li><li><a href="#tab5"><img src="placeholder.svg" style="width:20%;"></a></li>

        <li class="active"><a href="#tab1"><img src="placeholder.svg" style="width:25%"></a></li><li><a href="#tab2"><img src="placeholder.svg" style="width:25%;"></a></li><li><a href="#tab3"><img src="placeholder.svg" style="width:25%;"></a></li><li><a href="#tab4"><img src="placeholder.svg" style="width:25%;"></a></li>
```

So my exact question is why are the above 5 images not as wide as the 4 below if they both total 100% width and how do I get around this?

Comment: I am not specifying any borders in my code, so unless they are somehow auto applied by default, no. The borders around the circle in the image are part of the image.

Comment: this isn't an answer, but remove that width: 100% for the *, that sets the width of every element to 100%

Comment: Just tried it - no effect whatsoever.

Comment: @PetrasRepšys none of the code related to your question.

Comment: Ok, I will edit to emphasize the code of the images.

Comment: can you create a JSfiddle for the community?

Comment: Ok I have this theory:

Ipad 3 width is 1536 pixels.

1536 px * 0.2 (20% width) = 307.2 px
1536 px * 0.25 (25% width) = 384 px.

Maybe this has something to do with the slight width diffrence?

Comment: @racecarjonathan you can run the snippet I attached, but I just tested it without any code, just the html, body tags etc and images, and I still get the same result.